# How to get the extension alone in a file in shell script?

Tags: bash

I would like to extract only `tar.gz` from the following strings.

```
/root/abc/xzy/file_tar_src-5.2.8.23.tar.gz
```

or

```
/root/abc/xyz/file_tar_src-5.2.tar.gz
```

or

```
/root/abc/xyz/file_tar_src-5.tar.gz
```

out of all these strings (and many more) I need only `tar.gz` How do I extract them without concerned about the number of dots in them. I need to get the `tar.gz` in a variable.

Comment: What happens if a file name ends `.tar.bz2`?  Do you still want `tar.gz` or do you want `.tar.bz2`?  If you're only ever using `tar.gz`, you don't need to get the extension; you know it is `tar.gz`.  What happens with `file.c`?  Is that extension `.c` or `file.c` or is it just invalid because there's only one dot in the name?  Do you ever need the prefix, the non-extension?  Or do you mean 'get everything except the trailing `tar.gz`?  Do you want the terminal dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand why you need only `tar.gz`:

```
$ x=/root/abc/xyz/file_tar_src-5.tar.gz
$ y=${x##*[0-9].}
$ echo $y
tar.gz
```

Or:

```
$ x=/root/abc/xyz/file_tar_src-5.tar.gz
$ y=`echo $x | grep -o 'tar\.gz$'`
$ echo $y
tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky because you're not expecting the version number to be matched. We'll need more power than just plain wildcards. We can use bash's built-in `=~` regex operator to get the job done.

```
$ filename='/root/abc/xzy/file_tar_src-5.2.8.23.tar.gz'
$ [[ $filename =~ \.([^0-9]*)$ ]]
$ ext=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ echo "$ext"
tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ f='/root/abc/xzy/file_tar_src-5.2.8.23.tar.gz'
$ [[ $f =~ [^.]+\.[^.]+$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for. Are you trying to determine if the file ends with `tar.gz`?

```
if [[ $filename == *.tar.gz ]]
then
     echo "$filename is a gzipped compressed tar archive"
else
     echo "No, it's not"
fi
```

Are you attempting to find the suffix whether it's `tar.gz`, `tar.bz2` or just plain `tar`?

```
$suffix=${file##*.tar}
if [[ "$suffix" = "$file" ]]
then
    echo "Not a tar archive!"
else
    suffix="tar.$suffix"
    echo "Suffix is '$suffix'"
fi
```

Are you interested in the suffix, but if it's a tar.gz, you want to consider that the suffix:

```
filename='/root/abc/xzy/file_tar_src-5.2.8.23.tar.gz'
suffix=${filename##*.}   #This will be gz or whatever the suffix
rest_of_file=${filename%%.$suffix}  #This is '/root/abc/xzy/file_tar_src-5.2.8.23.tar'

# See if the rest of file has a tar suffix.
# If it does, prepend it to the current suffix
[[ $rest_of_file == *.tar ]] && suffix="tar.$suffix"

echo "The file suffix is '$suffix'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another on:

```
pathname="/root/abc/xzy/file_tar_src-5.2.8.23.tar.gz"

IFS='.'                               # field separator
declare -a part=( ${pathname} )       # split into an array
ext2="${part[*]: -2}"                 # use the last 2 elements
echo -e "${ext2}"
```